# ASP.NET Web API to be consumed by Angular application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, angularjs, sql-server

I am looking for a workaround to allow CRUD operations to be carried out on a database served by SQL Server 2000. From what I have read, SQL Server 2000 is incompatible with the Entity Framework provided by ASP.NET. I have seen a post detailing how to create a connection to the database with ADO.NET, but I've not found any illuminating articles for performing CRUDs.

For example, I have the following code that works with a MySQL server on my local machine:

```
public class RoutesDemoController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult One()
        {
            string querystring = "SELECT first_name FROM student";
            string connectionstring = "server=localhost;database=testdb;user id=uid;password=password;";
            string result = "";
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(querystring, connection);
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        result += reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    // always call close when done reading.
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }

            ViewBag.test = result;
            return View();
        }
}
```

However, I am trying to draft an API that can be called by the Angular's $http service in a manner like:

```
$http.get('/api').success(function(result){
    $scope.somefield = result;    
})
```

Any advice or guidance as to how to structure an application to consume an API in this manner would be greatly appreciated.

I've found a simplified example of an AngularJS app making an API calls as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app ="myApp">
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="myController">
           Response Data: {{data}} <br />
           Error: {{error}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

        myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {

            var onSuccess = function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.data = data;
            };

            var onError = function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.error = status;
            }

            var promise = $http.get("/demo/getdata").success(onSuccess).error(onError);

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In that example, `demo` is the API controller and `getdata` is the specific operation to get all entries, correct? How would I then construct my API controller to get the data when `$http.get("/demo/getdata/")` is called?

Comment: You can use SQL Server 2014 express, and for API a proper solution will be creating WebAPI controller.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to determine a solution that incorporates SQL Server 2000 as it is the product used at the company for which I'm interning.

Comment: You can't just cal ('/api') in MVC you have to call a Controller and method like ('api/RoutesDemo/One'), but your RoutesDemoController would need to be an api Controller.